# at job terminates almost immediately

Tags: bash, shell-script, at

I have a bash script, `/home/x/bin/asdf`, (which fires up a bunch of JVMs, piped together), and that works fine, when running directly from the command line like

```
/home/x/bin/asdf
```

However, when trying to run the same as

```
echo '/home/x/bin/asdf' | at SOME_TIME
```

Then I can see that the script and my JVMs start, but they terminate after one second or so. The initial output of those JVMs will indeed be sent by `at` in its email with the stdout, so it is working - briefly.

So why would the `asdf` script / the JVMs get terminated almost immediately? When running directly, it runs and outputs stuff indefinitely.

N.B. One of the JVMs makes a TCP connection. I cannot confirm that that is done when run by `at`. But if there's an error, it will be printed to stderr. But in `at`'s email there is no error.

Answer (score 3):

So the crucial difference between starting the script directly and having `at` run it was: the lack of stdin in the latter case.

So I can reproduce my script immediately shutting down by doing this:

```
/home/x/bin/asdf </dev/null
```

To fix it, I had to change one of those Java programs, which terminated when there was no input from stdin.

Comment: You might also want to redirect stderr to stdout: `2>&1`

Comment: @glennjackman why?